# Apache .htaccess: Is it possible to write an if condition for a cookie value check?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cookie

I want to write an if condition in an .htaccess file to check whether a cookie value is set.  Example code:

```
<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} == 'cookiename and value'">
    ...
</If>
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the cookie is set?   If you want to redirect, this question on StackOverflow might help: [How to do htaccess redirect based on cookie value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978726/how-to-do-htaccess-redirect-based-on-cookie-value)

Comment: Very much related cross-site question posted on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035133/writing-if-condition-in-htaccess-file-for-url-rewrite

Comment: That was posted by me only Bro :) Please help me regarding If condition if any, thank you

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick for me:

```
<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /(^|; )cookie-name\s*=\s*some-val(;|$)/>
```

The \s* part is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

**We can also use the below code**

```
<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /tenant=666/">
        SetEnv lang4 777
        Header add Set-Cookie "logged=%{lang4}e;"
</If>
```

Where **tenant** is the cookie-name and **777** is cookie-value